# Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <body> in <div>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I get the above mentioned warning in the console. I don't understand why. I have two matching `<body>` tags in `index.js` file. The complete warning is -

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <body> in <div>.
    in body (at pages/index.js:12)
    in div (at pages/index.js:11)
    in div (at pages/index.js:7)
    in Index (at _app.js:8)
    in MyApp
    in Container (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

Following the index.js file I'm using. I'm using Next.js with tailwindcss.

```
import Head from "next/head"
import SideNavbar from "../components/SideNavbar"
import MainPage from "../components/MainPage"

const Index = () => {
  return (
    <div className="mx-auto">
      <Head>
        <title>Manchester United</title>
      </Head>
      <body className="min-h-screen">
        <div className="flex flex-row">
          <SideNavbar />
          <MainPage>
            <div className="text-center px-2 py-6 text-5xl font-bold text-gray-200">
              Manchester United
            </div>
          </MainPage>
        </div>
      </body>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Index
```

The warning goes away if I replace the `<body>` tag with a `<div>` tag. The two custom components I use, `<SideNavbar />` and `<MainPage />`, don't use any `<body>` tags.

Comment: Inside your _document.js you must have div i.e. 

`<body>
    <Main />
   <NextScript />
</body>`

so the `Main` can't have another body tag via your _app.js

Comment: I don't have a `_document.js` file. I created this app using `npm init next-app`. I do have an `_app.js` file which I had to create to use tailwindcss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As React works, your React application is "injected" to HTML element which you define at `ReactDOM.render`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**But**, this element is already a child of `<body>` element.

> Warning: `validateDOMNesting(...)`: `<body>` cannot appear as a child of`<div>`.

Your error is just a **variation** of the same thing but as server-side rendering (Next.js) error.

---

By using `Next.js`, **this HTML is hidden from you** (check the HTML in the "vanilla" example in codesandbox attached).

Also, you can inspect the DOM tree at `source` tab in dev tools, there you will notice that two `<body>` elements exist.

Here is a small codesandbox code which demonstrates the error:

[image: Edit peaceful-bas-yhbof]

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML isn't correct. You cannot have a body-Tag inside a div-Tag. A basic HTML-Structure looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see. But in react, the return statement should be wrapped in one `<div>` element. Other wise I'll get a compile error. I remove the topmost `<div>` in the `Index` component in the code above and then I got the following error - `SyntaxError: /home/akshaj/projects_js/man-utd-explorer/pages/index.js: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (10:6)
`.

Comment: @theairbend3r  you cannot return *more than one* top level html tag/component from a react component. to solve this, you **can** use `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>` to wrap the multiple tags in an effectively, 'no-op' tag.